# PHP header location not redirecting after deleting directory

Tags: php, redirect

I have a button for my users to be able to delete a certain directory they created. They go to a confirmation page, and when they select "yes", this code gets activated:

```
$fileName=$_POST['filename'];
$siteName=$_POST['sitename'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$subdir=$_POST['subdir'];
if ($subdir=="yes") {
  $dirName=$_POST['dirname'];
  $path="../s/{$siteName}/{$dirName}";

    if (is_dir($path) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if (in_array($file->getBasename(), array('.', '..')) !== true)
            {
                if ($file->isDir() === true)
                {
                    rmdir($file->getPathName());
                }

                else if (($file->isFile() === true) || ($file->isLink() === true))
                {
                    unlink($file->getPathname());
                }
            }
        }

        return rmdir($path);
  header("location:edit.php?action=edit&user=$myusername"); 

    }
    else if ((is_file($path) === true) || (is_link($path) === true))
    {
        return unlink($path);
    }
  header("location:edit.php?action=edit&user=$myusername"); 

}
header("location: edit.php?action=edit&user=$myusername");
```

I've tried putting the `header("location: edit.php?action=edit&user=$myusername");` in all three of the above spots, but it never redirects. When I go to the page manually, the directory is deleted. My question is why it's not automatically redirecting?

Comment: add `exit();` right after redirect attempt so it doesn't keep executing more code and redirects right then...and don't put redirects after `return`s in a branch

Comment: Didn't work... after which redirect should I add it?

Comment: after those inside and if branch

Comment: Nope.. still doesn't work.

Comment: WARNING: `session_is_registered()` was deprecated in PHP5.3 and removed in PHP5.4. Use `isset($_SESSION['myusername']))` instead.

Comment: location with capitol L `Location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return rmdir(...)
header(....)`

you already returned, so header will never be sent

correct code:

```
rmdir(...);
header(...);
return;
```

---

also on the last line, this one is unnecessary